# "He was 'happily married' with two young children." Can somebody explain to me the meaning of "happily married" in that sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

Consider the following sentence:

> He was **happily married** with two young children.

Can somebody explain to me the meaning of **"happily married"** in that sentence? Is **"happily married"** an idiom?

I found in Cambridge Dictionary the following:

> [**happily**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/happily): in a happy way

I also found in Cambridge Dictionary the following:

> [**married**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/married): having a wife or husband

These definitions don't fit together.

Comment: Where's your confusion? What did an online dictionary tell you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It only tell married means **to have husband or wife that's it.**

Comment: And *happily* what does that mean? However I'm pretty sure that the phrase can be found in dictionaries, you need to close it with speech marks "happily married"

Comment: @Mari-LouA happily=in a happy way, married=to have husband or wife, butttt.... This definition don't fit together, that's why I asked

Comment: It's just saying someone is **in a happy marriage**  definition: scroll down until you see the phrase mentioned https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/married

Comment: Seeing as this is a language site, you should know that: `It only tell` is ungrammatical. When the subject is singular i.e. "it" a verb in the present tense must have an "s" suffix i.e `tells`. Also, the verb *to tell* usually requires a direct object, this is often a pronoun so in your case the best construction is **it only tells me that** *‘married’ means* …

Comment: People can be **unhappily married", also.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Do you go to the same English Class as Sam?  Your edit seems to suggest you know what Sam's English teacher wrote on the board.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou Like James K said, unless you know for a fact where the sentence came from (and I don't think you do), you should not be editing it to say the teacher wrote it on the board. Please look at the edit I made to the question, which doesn't introduce any guesses as to where the sentence came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no mystery here.  Just a little contextual interpretation.

Married is an adjective, and you have the definition.

In context I would understand "He" to mean the husband, and that "he" is married to someone, hence "he" has a wife or husband.

And "happily" describes the marriage. There are few fights or arguments. If the marriage is happy, then the people who are married are happy to be married and don't want to separate.

This is a collation. These two words are often put together, but the meaning can be understood from the meanings of the individual words.

Comment: Can I say **they are  happily in the state of matrimony**??

Comment: There is no "they" in the OP's original sentence. The sentence begins with "**He was** happily married…" I don't think such a high-rep user such as yourself should be answering questions that show no effort, no research and are extremely easy to answer too. But that's just me.

Comment: @Sam You can say "They got married and they lived happily" or "They are married and they live happily" or  "They are married and they live happily together".

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou - using a dictionary is part of language learning.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou [What **don't you** like in my edit and answer?]

Comment: I edited that "they".... I wonder why the edit didn't stick. It was just a mistake.

Comment: @Marios *Edits cannot be downvoted*.  So I have no idea what you mean by "my edit was downvoted". Or how your comment relates to my answer (which I think I've now fixed)

Comment: @Lambie Hi! I am sorry! I didn't see your edit and your answer.

Comment: @James K Hi! You are right. I don't go to the same English Class as Sam. I had to edit the question in a better way.Fortunately Laurel helped me! He edited the question and now the question is not downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The collocation **happily married** means "in a stable marriage". The marriage is established and steady. The marriage is not "on the rocks" like a ship about to sink in a storm.