# Parsing of the sentence "I have been happily married for nine years."

Tags: meaning-in-context, parsing

**I have been happily married for nine years.**

I want parsing of this sentence.

Married I think adjective and happily is an Adverb.

Here **happily** mean I think -In a happy manner

Comment: Didn't you already ask something similar: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341524/he-was-happily-married-with-two-young-children-can-somebody-explain-to-me-t

Comment: @JamesK it's a different aspect of the question.you didn't clarify my doubt.

Comment: It the same aspect, the meaning of "happily married".

Comment: @JamesK I am asking how the adjective is being modified by the adverb by coming before it.

Comment: You accepted James's answer which explained what _happily married_ means.

Comment: @KateBunting This time my question is different.

Comment: Adverbs can modify adjectives, e.g. "incredibly fast", "very talkative", "intermittently bright". Although I'd view "happily married" as an idiomatic compound adjective.

Comment: @StuartF I want to know what this idiomatic compound adjective.

Comment: "Married" is an adjective modified by the adverb "happily".

Comment: I think it's unhelpful to think of ***married*** here as a "verb". Sure - the usage is *derived* from a past participle - but that participle is being used ***adjectivally***. Syntactically, it's no different to, say, [*I have been happily **single** for most of my life*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+been+happily+single%22) or [*I have been happily **celibate** longer than she's been alive.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+been+happily+celibate%22) Just think of it as ***adverb modifying adjective*** if such terminology seems important to you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have been happily single for most of my life- Is this implies For most of his life he didn't have a romantic relationship with anyone in a pleased way.

Comment: "in a pleased way" isn't a valid expression in English, but even if it was, that would be an overtly *adverbial element modifying a **verb***, which as I just commented is an unhelpful way to look at things here. Just think of *[being] **happily married*** as a ***state***, not an ***action / activity.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers likewise, *single as an adjective * implies *a state of being unmarried*, *happily* mean (according to Cambridge dictionary)-In a happy way, so After combining both word the meaning should be (I think) **To be in a state of being unmarried in a happy way**.

Comment: I give up. If you're determined to interpret the construction as based on ***verbs***, that's your choice. But I don't think it's helpful. Consider *I've been **fairly** celibate most of my adult life*. Obviously ***fairly*** there doesn't adverbially modify ***been*** to mean ***in a fair way***. You should parse ***happily married*** more like ***fairly celibate***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been happily married for nine years.

Yes, *happily* is an adverb modifying the adjective *married*.

> happily adverb
> 3
> : in a happy manner or state

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/happily)

Comment: What's the meaning of married here 1)Having a wife or husband or2)united in marriage/joined in marriage & how it is being modified by the adverb "happily"